# FLVPlayback went blank in fullscreen AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flvplayback

I'm making a fullscreen swf contains 2 scenes in Adobe Flash using AS3. In the first scene, there is one button named btn, which is it will go to Scene 2 when it be clicked. In scene 2, there is FLVPlayback name player. And that's scene went blank when I clicked button btn in the scene 1 :(
I tried to use player.fullScreenTakeOver = false; in the button btn action in scene 1, bu it's not working, because scene 1 can't identify player which is in the scene 2.
Please help, here is my code :

SCENE 1

```
stop();
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
import fl.video.FLVPlayback;

btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ac);
function ac(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    player.fullScreenTakeOver = false;
    gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 2");
}
```

SCENE 2

```
stop();
import fl.video.FLVPlayback;
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
player.fullScreenTakeOver = false;
function startAnimation():void
{
    player.play();
}
function stopAnimation():void
{
    player.stop();
}
```

Comment: If `player` exists on Scene 2 then don't have player code in Scene 1. Just tell it to go to Scene 2, then Scene 2 itself can do the `player.fullScreenTakeOver = false;` part of code. Also you cannot enter or exit Full Screen mode without user interaction (they must press a button or keyboard) so don't be surprised if not auto-working on when you start on Scene 1. About the "...went blank" did you test that the video can play correctly? Can you hear sound when you tell your `FLVPlayback` instance to play?

Comment: Thank you for answering..
I tried that too, I deleted `player.fullScreenTakeOver = false;` in Scene 1 and move it to Scene 2, but the video still overtaking the screen. I checked my video too, it works perfectly. Those code works too if the video in Scene 1 too, but not working if the video in Scene 2. Please help :( @VC.One

Comment: I can't seem to re-create your problem. I used **FLVPlayback 2.5** from Components menu (ctrl+F7) and dragged onto stage of Scene 2. I didn't use the start/stop Animation functions. Just used `player.source = "video1.flv";` after the `player.fullScreenTakeOver = false;` line and it works fine. The video was still a small box on full screen canvas. If set `player.fullScreenTakeOver = true;` then video itself is now fullscreen.

Comment: I tried your code. but the result is still the same :( if I test movie, it works. but if I play the swf from the folder, it's still went blank...Here's my code:
SCENE 1 :
`stop();
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
import fl.video.FLVPlayback;

btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ac);
function ac(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 2");
}`

SCENE 2
`import fl.video.FLVPlayback;
player.fullScreenTakeOver = false;

player.source = "game.mp4";`
@VC.One

Comment: Is the folder on disk or online? Is the MP4 file placed in the same folder as SWF file? Also if this folder is online then use the the full path to mp4 like `player.source = "http://example.com/folder/game.mp4";`

Comment: in the same folder with my fla file. I don't know why is it still not working when I play the swf file from folder :( @VC.One

Comment: I don't know either. I don't understand why your code has `import fl.video.FLVPlayback;` unless you also do a `player : FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback;`? Did you try dragging the version **2.5** on to stage instead with instance name **player** like I did in my other above comment? Also make sure in your publish settings you set "access local files" and also that you are not loading anything from the internet in this mode. If all fails just send a link to the SWF file and I will try it with my own game.mp4 file.

Comment: @VC.One I use version 2.5 on my stage... and on my FLVplayback, I set my video game.mp4 as source in component parameters panel. I make sure publish settings access local files. Would you help me ? Can I send my fla file to you?